# Google Forms / Apps Script / Hangouts Chat - Bot message content sending individually instead of together

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-hangouts

I'm trying to make a Google Hangouts Chat Bot that detects when a form has been filled in, and sends the responses of the most recent form submission to Hangouts Chat using a bot. I have built this off existing code (my JS / GAS knowledge is near zero), mainly based on the GitHub [TSFormBot](https://github.com/techstreams/TSFormBot) repo. The issue is, it is sending each response invidiually as a different message, instead of 1 single message with all of the content.

For exmaple, a 4 question form causes the bot to send 4 individual replies, with one of the different answers in each. Could you please help me see where I'm going wrong, so I could get the content of all 4 answers in a single response?

Thanks!

**Current code:**

```js
function postToRoom(e) {
    var formResponses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
  var options, options, url; 
  url = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('WEBHOOK_URL');
  if (url) {
    try { 
      payload = {
        "cards": [
          {
            "header": {
              "title": "There is a new request!",
              "imageUrl": "https://images.emojiterra.com/google/android-10/128px/1f916.png",
              "imageStyle": "IMAGE",
            },
                        "sections": [
              {
                "widgets": [
                  {
                    "textParagraph": {
                      "text": '<b>'+ (
                        itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() + ' ' + itemResponse.getResponse())',

                    }
                  }
                ] 
              },
              {

                "widgets": [
                  {
                    "buttons": [
                      {
                        "textButton": {
                          "text": "GO TO RESPONSE",
                          "onClick": {
                            "openLink": {
                              "url": e.response.getEditResponseUrl()
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "textButton": {
                          "text": "GO TO FORM",
                          "onClick": {
                            "openLink": {
                              "url": FormApp.getActiveForm().getEditUrl()
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ] 
          } 
        ]
      }    
      options = {
        'method' : 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload)
      };
      UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
    } catch(err) {
      Logger.log('FormBot: Error processing Bot. ' + err.message);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('FormBot: No Webhook URL specified for Bot');
  }
}
```

**The Form:**

[image: The form]

**The Bot Response**

[image: Bot Response]

Comment: I'd use for onFormSubmit for the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having it's because, inside your `for` loop, you are sending every time your payload using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);`, therefore you need to do it in this way:

```js
// Previous stuff
for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
  // Do something 
}
// Do more stuff
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Knowing that. The first thing I changed in your code, it was to create a ***payload*** object, which would possess a `sections` attribute that later will be populated.

```js
var payload = {
        "cards": [{
          "header": {
           "title": "TSFormBot",
           "subtitle": "Form Notifications Bot",
           "imageUrl": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/techstreams/TSFormBot/master/notifications.png",
           "imageStyle": "IMAGE"
           },
        "sections": []
        }
       ]
      };
```

Having the ***payload*** object, I created a function for populating the `sections` attribute, there you will have the `for` loop and after filling the object with all the responses, I added the two buttons:

```js
/*
 * Build Payload 
 * 
 * @param {Object} payload 
 * @param {ItemResponse[]} itemResponses
 * @param {FormResponse} formResponse
 */
function populateCard(payload, itemResponses, formResponse){
 for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
     payload["cards"][0]["sections"].push({
       "widgets": [{
         "textParagraph": {
            "text": itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() + ' ' + itemResponse.getResponse()
           }
         }
       ]
    });
  }
  payload["cards"][0]["sections"].push({
            "widgets": [
              {
                "buttons": [
                      {
                        "textButton": {
                          "text": "GO TO RESPONSE",
                          "onClick": {
                            "openLink": {
                              "url": formResponse.getEditResponseUrl()
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "textButton": {
                          "text": "GO TO FORM",
                          "onClick": {
                            "openLink": {
                              "url": FormApp.getActiveForm().getEditUrl()
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
              }
        ]
      }   
  );
  return payload;
}
```

After all that, you will able to send the request using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);`. Your `postToRoom(e)` function would look like this:

```js
/*
 * Process Form Submission
 * 
 * @param {Object} e - form submit event object
 */
function postToRoom(e) {
  var formResponses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  formResponse.getEditResponseUrl()
  var options, options, url; 
  url = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('WEBHOOK_URL');
  if (url) {
    try { 
      var payload = {
        "cards": [{
          "header": {
           "title": "TSFormBot",
           "subtitle": "Form Notifications Bot",
           "imageUrl": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/techstreams/TSFormBot/master/notifications.png",
           "imageStyle": "IMAGE"
           },
        "sections": []
        }
       ]
      };
      // Call this function to populate the card with the responses 
      var PopulatedPayload = populateCard(payload, itemResponses, formResponse);  
      options = {
        'method' : 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload)
      };
      UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
    } catch(err) {
      Logger.log('TSFormBot: Error processing Bot. ' + err.message);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('TSFormBot: No Webhook URL specified for Bot');
  }
}
```

### Card Response

[image]

### Docs

I used these docs to help you:

- [Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response).
- [Class Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form).
- [Card Formatting Messages](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards).

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you so much! It makes sense now someone has shown it to me. I really appreciate it. :D

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad my answer really helped you!